# When can we interchange limits of functions with limits of sequences?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I just noticed how the definitions for $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x) = L$, and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}s_n = s$ are essentially the same thing.

Because of this, are we allowed to "swap out" $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ with $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}s_n$ if {$s_n$} is the equivalent sequence of $f(x)$, regardless of whether or not the limit exists? For instance, if we wanted to evaluate $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}$sin(x), is it okay to instead consider $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}s_n$, where $s_n$ = sin(n)?

Comment: In the example you gave, neither limit exists.  But you might consider $f(x) = \sin(\pi x)$ and $s_n = \sin(\pi n)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Restricting a function of a real variable to its values on a discrete set can lose information. So we can't swap one for the other willy-nilly.

By “equivalent sequence” I guess you mean setting $s_n = f(n)$. Here are some things you can say:

- If $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = L$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} s_n = L$.
- Contrapositively, if $\lim_{n\to\infty} s_n$ does not exist, then $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ does not exist.

But now consider the function $f(x) = \sin \pi x$. Setting $s_n = f(n)$, we see that $\lim_{n\to\infty} s_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} 0 = 0$. But $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ does not exist. So it is possible for the sequence to have a limit while the function does not.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I wasn't aware that the contrapositive to the statement "If $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = L$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} s_n = L$." is true, so that's good to know. It took me some time to understand why your example is true since I had to think about how $x \in \mathbb{R}$, but $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @Anonymous73648 Note that the contrapositive of a true statement is always true.

Answer (score 4):

You’re on the right track. We can say a limit exists at a point in the extended real numbers iff for every sequence $\{x_n\}$ converging to that point, then $\{f(x_n)\}$ converges to $L$.